# Spring Data MongoDB reactive distinct not working

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Consider the following dependency:

- `org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` (2.0.2.RELEASE)

I'm having a collection of which I need to retrieve distinct values. However when I'm using a query method to retrieve a `Flux` of distinct values, it is not working. I defined the following query method, using a closed projection `IdentifierOnly`:

```
@Repository
public interface FooBarRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<FooBar, String> {

    Flux<IdentifierOnly> findDistinctByFooAndBar(String foo, String bar);
}
```

The document / collection class:

```
@Document
public class FooBar {

    private String identifier; // not unique
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    // extra fields

    // getters and setters
}
```

The closed projection:

```
public interface IdentifierOnly {

    getIdentifier();
}
```

However the query that is executed and logged by the `ReactiveMongoTemplate` is the following: `find using query: { "foo" : "xxxx", "bar" : "yyyy" } fields: Document{{identifier=1}} for class: class org.example.models.FooBar in collection: fooBar` and is not returning any results in a distinct way, because it contains duplicates.

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve distinct values (identifiers) based on a specific query?

Comment: Hint: You don't need `@Repository` on Spring Data repository interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

That does not work (yet). I filed [DATAMONGO-1985](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1985) to investigate how we can integrate distinct queries.

## Explanation

MongoDB provides a distinct operation that requires exactly one field for retrieving distinct values. This operation is available on the Template API but not through the repository API. From a repository perspective, there's actually no possibility to specify the field which should be used for a distinct operation.

The code above forms an interesting case which uses all ingredients (distinct keyword, closed projection with a single field) that would be necessary to derive a distinct query.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and good explanation, hoping to see such a feature in the near future. I´ll look into the Template API, see if I can get it to work in the meantime.